# An attempt to show that if $M = \max(A)$ then $M = \sup(A)$

Tags: real-analysis

I believe this is very simple but I want to check if I am doing this correctly.

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $M\in A$ such that $x \le M$ for all $x \in A$. Hence $M=\max(A)$.

I am using the following theorem:

$\alpha = \sup(A)$ if and only if:

(i) $\alpha$ is a upper bound for $A$

(ii) $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists some $x \in A$ such that $x > \alpha - \epsilon$.

Here is my attempt:

Since $x \le M$ for all $x \in A$, it follows by definition that $M$ is an upper bound for $A$. So (i) is shown.

Now, recall that $M \in A$ and let $x = M$. It immediately follows that $M > M - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Hence condition (ii) is also shown.

Therefore $M=\sup(A)$.

Comment: isn't maximum defined as a supremum that is in the set? it's like trying to prove a blue shirt is a shirt.

Comment: As far as I understand, not necessarily. If defined the way I did on the question it does not exactly meet the definition for supremum. It is defined exactly as an upper bound though.

Comment: if the second line is your definition for the maximum then yes the proof is correct, however the theorem is not really needed. look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct, but the theorem is not really needed. you could simply say:
supremum is the smallest upper bound so $sup(A)≤M$,
and since it's an upper bound for $A$ and $M$ is in A: $\sup(A)≥M$ therefore $\sup(A)=M$

Comment: Thanks! Very easy to follow. I see now that I didn't need any other theorem.